# Spring Data : Complicated queries with Specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42324604/1498586) method for using specifications come with query params to generate dynamic query. it is works fine. but in this way I can use simple `.and()` or `.or()`.

my question is what is the best practice for handle complicated queries like `where ((a & b)|(c & d) & (x))` with specification with dynamic input?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate dynamic queries (if you don't know how many elements you will have in your or/and) the best solution for that is to create some builder class for generating queries. In example: [SpecificationBuilder](https://github.com/mateuszwinnicki/mwin-specifications/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/mateuszwinnicki/specification/builder/SpecificationBuilder.java) from my github.

When you know how many elements you will have I recommend you to use Specification like (just example):

```
(root, query, builder) -> {
    return builder.and(
        builder.equal(root.get("id"), "1"),
        builder.equal(root.get("name"), "name"),
        builder.or(
            builder.equal(root.get("id"), "2"),
            builder.equal(root.get("name"), "enam")
        )
    );
}
```